# How to use api to 'click' tree view?

Tags: visual-studio-code, treeview, vscode-extensions

I add a tree view to sidebar in my VSCode extension. And I found if I click the sidebar icon, the getChildren function will be called.  Is there any api to make the "click" in my extension code rather than user mouse click?
[picture of sidebar icon in extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKqyi.png).
Because there is a business scenario that needs to implement some automated operations that do not require user operations.
Thank you!

I read the [tree view document](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/tree-view), but I can't find an interface that can implement this function:(

Comment: you can call the refresh event of the treeview

Comment: Do you mean this function this._onDidChangeTreeData.fire() ?  I have tried the fire function, but it did not work (the getChildren funtion will not be called unless I click the icon by my mouse.)

Comment: You could try ` vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.view.extension.<yourViewContainerNameHere");
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
vscode.commands.executeCommand("workbench.view.extension.<yourViewContainerNameHere")
```

Every contributed view automatically gets such a command created.  In your case use your View Container ID.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/74465881/836330 for more automatically created TreeView or WebView commands.